# Google Maps API, setDirections() must not update map's position

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

From what I learned from some sources, the **setDirections()** method automatically updates the map when associated directions have changed. I want the position to be set using **map.fitBounds()** method instead of the automatic update from the **setDirections()** method. Thank you.

```
directionsService.route({
    origin: {lat: 13.259876, lng: 123.759846},
    destination: {lat: 13.141377, lng: 123.759846},
    travelMode: 'WALKING'
}, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
directionsDisplay = new DirectionsRenderer({preserveViewport:true})
```